# Extending Angular 2 dynamic forms to hide fields for certain values if conditions are met

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms

I was following the example given on Dynamic Forms from the Angular 2 documentation (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html). In this example you are shown how to create forms dynamically, based on metadata that describes the business object model.

This roughly looks as follows:
I have a `YesNoQuestion` class that describes how my questions are formatted.

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';
export class YesNoQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'radio';
  options: {key: string, value: string}[] = [];

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.options = [
      {key: 'true', value: 'Yes'},
      {key: 'false', value: 'No'}
    ];
  }
}
```

Each form is generated in my `dynamic-form.component`:

```
<div>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-group">
      <df-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></df-question>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div *ngIf="payLoad" class="form-row">
    <strong>Saved the following values</strong><br>{{payLoad}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The dynamic-form calls the dynamic-form-question for each single question `dynamic-form-question.component`:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">

  <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>
  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">

    <div class="form-group" *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">
      <div *ngFor="let opt of question.options">
        <input type="radio" [formControlName]="question.key" [value]="opt.key" />  {{opt.value}}
      </div>
    </div>

    ... Some extra form types ...

  </div>
  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
</div>
```

Now I can generate a form by simply inserting a questions object like the following:

```
let questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [
  new YesNoQuestion({
    key: 'a',
    label: 'Label A',
  }),
  new YesNoQuestion({
    key: 'b',
    label: 'Label B',
  }),
  new YesNoQuestion({
    key: 'c',
    label: 'Label C',
  }),
  new TextareaQuestion({
    key: 'd',
    label: 'Label D',
  }),
```

Now I am looking for a way to let these question be dependent of each other. I for example only want to see question A, and if yes is answered for question A I want to show question B. If no is answered I want to show question C.

Would something like that be implementable in my current approach? I haven't found a good tactic yet, I tried to add an attribute `hide` but didn't know how to reference other field values.

Comment: This is a great question.  We have a very similar set of functionality in Angular 1.x.  We are hoping to move this to Angular 2 someday, but there seems to be a dearth of information and experience in this type of complex form manipulation.  We have a separate service which determines the visibility of the form fields and questions.  I wonder if an ng-if on or around your df-question tags referencing such a service would work for you.